# How to Update an Object inside an Array inside a MongoDB Collection using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This Is An Expense Tracker Application

I'm Trying to Make An Update Route where The User Can Update the Value of An Expense

[image: Heres A Snapshot Of My Database Model]

For Example, I want to update the First Expense Name from Bike to Bike Rental & Amount from 250 to 500

And similarly, make a generic endpoint where the user can update any expense whenever necessary

Here A Snapshot of My Express Get Route & The Patch route which I want to fill

[image]

The ObjectID of the Entire Collection which is 607bbb07e1ebb63a3033af15 will be sent to the backend from the Frontend.

I am using Express, Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run update on the model you have created like this:

```
const filter = {_id :"(*User Id Here*)", "Expenses._id": "(*Expense Id Here*)"}; //check the type of _id if this doesn't work
const query = {$set: {"Expenses.$.Name" : "value"}};

User.update(filter, query);
```

Or,

```
User.update({_id :"ObjectId(pass id)", "Expense._id" : ObjectId'pass id'}, {'$set': {'Expenses.$.Name': 'name update'});
```

Similarly, You can do this for any key in the object provided that the key exists in it. Now this will check the

Comment: The Above Query is getting executed however It Isn't getting updated in the database.